# Implicitly has an `any` type becoz index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, zxing, angular12

I am using Zxing Scanner component in Angular version 12.
I faced this error in many places..

```
/**
 * Returns a valid BarcodeFormat or fails.
 */
private getBarcodeFormat(format: string | BarcodeFormat): BarcodeFormat {
  return typeof format === 'string'
    ? BarcodeFormat[format.trim().toUpperCase()]
    : format;
}
```

Error is in this line `[format.trim().toUpperCase()]` and when I hover it will show `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)`.

[image: This is the error code I screenshot it... Please view it]

**Why this error came?? How do I resolve it??**

I need a perfect solution without change any configuration in my *angular.json* or *package.json*

Comment: Can you show your code, not as an image, but as a code in the question? It is easy for the people who answer your question to refer the code without going to another link and also easy to copy and paste.

Comment: Can you please replace type of format any to string?

Comment: Okay Please remove the BarcodeFormat after the string. It will resolve your issue

Comment: Put only this in your input (format: string)

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, i replace as (format: string) and still error @AmanGojariya

Comment: I replace the format type string to any. but still error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the error occurred is because `format` is a string and can be anything so when you use it in `BarcodeFormat`, typescript doesn't know whether `format` is one of the keys of `BarcodeFormat`.

Therefore, we need to tell typescript `format` is actually part of the keys in `BarcodeFormat`.

To do it, we can use the combination of `keyof typeof` to get the keys in `BarcodeFormat` and do type casting on `format`.

```js
private getBarcodeFormat(format: string | BarcodeFormat): BarcodeFormat {
    return typeof format === "string"
      ? BarcodeFormat[format.trim().toUpperCase() as keyof typeof BarcodeFormat]
      : format;
}
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-cloud-bz51m?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) for demonstration.

Comment: Yes. It's work now.. Thank you so much for your valuable time on this explanation

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find it useful =). Here is the link of how to accept answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yes, Now accepted. Sorry... I tried to vote for the answer but I need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote.
and I don't know about accept the answer. So I didn't.

Comment: I know. is okay. haha. you will earn point as well so don't hesitate to accept the answer that solved your problem =]